# Netty channel().read() on channel without any data currently present

Tags: websocket, netty

im trying to figure out how to implement back-pressure in netty and i found that `autoread=true` and using explicit `ctx.channel().read()` might work but im not sure how it works and was not able to find more details.

Specifically, i was wondering what happens if `read()` is called. Are the semantics that netty will try to read from underlying channel (lets say websocket connection)? What if there are no data ready to be read? Will the read succeed without reading any data? Or will i be guaranteed that if i call read once, it will keep trying to read until there are some data available?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read()` basically just tell the `Channel` to read the next chunk of data when there is something ready, which either means directly or at some point later. So yeah you are guaranteed that if you call `read()` it will read at some point.

Comment: maybe to clarify -- does calling `read()` have any implications? Or is it idempotent, meaning it doesn't really metter and it will just trigger next single read regardless of how many times you call `read()`

Comment: Yes that is the case... At least if we talk about the Channel itself. That said if you have a `ChannelOutboundHandler` in your pipeline it may re-act differently here.

Comment: yes, im thinking about channel -- the use case is to implement backpressure (not read more data from socket/kernel until my app is ready to process it)

Comment: for the Channel it does not matter how often you call read()...

Comment: thanks a lot! and maybe one more question if you would be so kind ... this probably won't work great with things like `WebsocketFrameAggregator`, right? the idea is:

pipeline contains:
- `websocketServerHandler`
- `websocketAggregatorHandler`
- `myHandler`

and in my handler i call `read()` after processing full frame, that will only trigger one `read()` call ... so in my head this might read first websocket frame, but if it's not a final frame, aggregator will store it internally and won't trigger `myHandler`, thus no other `read()` will happen 

is that analysis correct pls? :)

Comment: For this to work you can add the `FlowControlHandler` in the pipeline

Comment: You guys have thought of everything 